# How to use flexbox in Angular

Tags: angular, flexbox

I'm learning Angular and when I try to use flexbox on the body it doesn't seem to work, but using it on other elements works. For example what I'm trying to do is I made a simple counter app and I want to center everything but it doesn't seem to work.

I googled and all I could see was people using Angular Flex-Layout so is that what I need to use or am I missing something?

app.component.html

```
<div class="content">
    <h2 class="counter">{{num}}</h2>
    <button class="btn" (click)="increment($event)">+</button>
    <button class="btn" (click)="decrement($event)">-</button>
</div>
```

app.component.css

```
body {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Please add [a minimal runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the post & what you have tried so far(i.e., your code that is not working) so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML after build is

```html
<body>
  <app-root>
    <!-- HTML Code of your component -->
  </app-root>
</body>
```

So you're missing a step here.

In your `app.component.scss` file :

```css
:host {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The component CSS files are scoped.**  That means they only applies to elements in the component (app.component.html in your case)

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

If you want to write styles outside components, you can use global stylesheets, e.g. `src/styles.css`, defined in `angular.json`. They work just like regular css

[external-and-global-style-files](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#external-and-global-style-files)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `justify-content` and `align-items` to align the content to center. You will also need to set `height` and `min-height` of `html` and `body` elements.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

`align-items` property aligns the item on the cross axis.

`justify-content` aligns the item on the main axis.

Comment: I tried that before it didn't work :(. Thank you!

Comment: The answer is updated, try also align-items to align on cross axis (which is vertical in this case).

Comment: The question is actually about the problem with the `body` vs `:host` selector that angular uses. Not with flexbox itself